# Is a comma necessary before an adjunct that-clause?

Tags: punctuation, commas

CGEL by Pullum (Page 969) says:

> **4.7 Adjunct in clause structure**
>
> There are a handful of constructions where a declarative content clause functions as adjunct rather than complement.
>
> (a) With subject + predicator order
>
> [52] i *What has happened, **that you are looking so worried**?*
>
> ii *‘This is my party card’, he said, holding it high, **that all might see it**.*
>
> iii ***The more we talked**, the more I liked her.*

In both [52i] and [52ii], there's a comma before an adjunct clause that starts with a subordinator *that*.

When the subordinator *that* is clearly marking the start of an adjunct clause as in [52i] and [52ii], do you still need a comma before *that*? Or is this comma rather optional?

Be it necessary or optional, is the comma there to show that the *that*-clause is an adjunct of the main clause, as opposed to a complement?

Because I don't think you need a comma before a *that*-clause that is a complement of a main clause:

> **What has happened, that has never happened before?*

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, the first one is optional, commonly no `that`, but the second one is necessary.

But the statement `What has happened, that has never happened before?`, this `that` references to what has happened, means `that situation`.

Comment: Hello, Ayon. As Matt Gutting has said: << Hi! What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer; one that you can support with authoritative references (in this case grammar or published article). Edit your question and put in your support; then we'll be able to vote up your answer! >> and as MετάEd has said << A good answer is comprehensive and contains evidence showing why it is correct....

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged. Answers which consist of virtually nothing but an unsupported statement or a citation are not useful and may be subject to deletion – even correct answers. For help writing a good answer, see How to Answer. >> // Isn't it possible that adding the comma is used to indicate that _the declarative content clause functions as adjunct rather than complement_?

Comment: Please don't use the `backtick` to highlight words. This usage is highly discouraged here and on ELL.